# Custom indent minified file

Tags: indentation, substitute, formatting

At work I'm forced to work on custom mapping-files which map relations between objects of different systems.

These mappings, which are basically [Jinja templates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jinja_(template_engine)#Example), are unfortunately stored in single lines, so that a simple mapping like (just made that up for illustration purposes):

```
{% for color in colors %}
    {% if color == 'white' or color == 'blue' or color == 'magenta' %}
        FF
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Would be stored in the CSV, together with some additional attributes, like this:

```
Name,SomeFlag,Mapping
Mapping_Blue,TRUE,`{% for color in colors %}{% if color == 'white' or color == 'blue' or color == 'magenta' %}FF{% endif %}{% endfor %}`
```

As you can imagine, this is a pain to work with during day to day editing, for reviews, etc. In practice I typically find myself substituting `}` with line breaks and then do the indentation manually.

I wonder if there's a way to do this in vim, so that I could view the described CSV in a format similar to this:

```
Name,SomeFlag,Mapping
Mapping_Blue,TRUE,`
    {% for color in colors %}
        {% if color == 'white' or color == 'blue' or color == 'magenta' %}
            FF
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}`
```

Ideally, it would also collapse it back into one line when saving the file. Is there a way to achieve this? I'm using vim, but switching to neovim would be possible.

Best, Phil

Comment: You could probably write some autocommands, but there would be some edge cases. Might not be a bad idea to write a parser & formatter program in some language that you can use to switch between formats.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Interesting, didn't know about autocommands. Just looked into it and it seems like the right thing to do. Could just do the expanding / collapsing of lines with an autocommand on read or write, and then leave the formatting to an existing Jinja formatter. Thanks!

Comment: If you get something working, please post an answer!